# Media query not working(code provided)

Tags: html, css, media-queries

For some reason I can't get my media queries working.... Can someone explain what's going on?

Screen size is at 241 (chrome, ie, ff)

CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px)
{
    body
      {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
      }

  #header
    {
      display: none;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Test</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes' rel='stylesheet'  type='text/css'>
 </head>
 <body> 
     <div id="header">
         <p>This is my header</p>
     </div>

     <p>This is a paragraph</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

edited for misspelling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check that your media queries are the last items in your style sheet and are not being overwritten by other applied styles e.g.

```
    <style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px)
    {
    body
      {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: black;
      }
      #header
        {
          display: none;
        }
    }
    body {background-color: white;}
    </style>
```

the example I've given will never change the background-color of the body element as the styling below the media query will over-ride it

Comment: *smacks forehead*  I knew that..... Guess 36 hours no sleep is getting to me.  Calling it quits, good night!

Answer (score 1):

What you have works by itself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 500px)
        {
        body
          {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: black;
          }
          #head
            {
              display: none;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes' rel='stylesheet'  type='text/css'>
 </head>
 <body> 
     <div id="head">
         <p>This is my header</p>
     </div>

     <p>This is a paragraph</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Check if you have any other media queries that might be overriding this one. Otherwise maybe it's a link to your stylesheet that's the issue,